# Help for Staking Pallet! Preventing oversubscription on validator nodes

Tags: staking, validator, pallet-staking

Does anyone know the difference between **maxNominatorsCount** and **maxNominatorRewardedPerValidator** in Staking pallet? Which one is responsible for causing oversubscription on validator nodes?

Answer (score 3):

`maxNominatorsCount` is the maximum number of nomination intentions that can be set. In other words, it is limit on the maximum number of nominators. If set to `None`, no limit will exist.

`maxNominatorRewardedPerValidator` the one causing oversubscription, and means the number of "active nominators" that can be rewarded by a single validator.

To understand what is a nomination intention and what is an active nominator, see [this link](https://polkadot.network/blog/staking-update-february-2022/#staking-terminology).